# Fetch data from Mongodb using Pymongo and serve as a WS

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have some data in my mongodb and i want to pull selective data from it (using query) and then serve it over http as a webservice.
 Here is my code so far,

```
from flask import Flask

from pymongo import MongoClient
conn  = MongoClient('172.16.1.195', 27017)
db = conn.Views_AllTables
collection = db.SubjectViews

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test1")
def data():
    return  collection.find_one()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5001,debug=True)
```

The app is running but i get no data at locahost:5001/test1
I was expecting to get atleast one row using the .fine_one() function.
What i am trying to implement is a selective query based access model using tags.
Can some one guide me?

Thank you,
Anmol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was easy. Just wrote the mongo query in find("query here").